# Update Database with Dataset

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-update, dataset

I have a Form with a Datagrid displaying data from a Dataset called AgendaDPDataSet.

The table being used is `Oradores`.
The Binding Navigator has this Code:

```
Private Sub OradoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
              Handles OradoresBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

    Me.Validate()
    Me.OradoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.OradoresTableAdapter.Update(Me.AgendaDPDataSet.Oradores)
```

But, when I run it, it only displays the data; it doesn’t Save, Update or Delete records.
The message it returns is:

> Additional information: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand to transfer the DataRow collection with modified lines.

I can’t figure out what am I missing.

Is there someone who knows why this is happening?

Comment: You need to show us how your OradoresTableAdapter is created and if you have called methods/ set properties and that instance

Comment: Is this what you need? http://www.esferinfinita.com/stack

Comment: Not all of that but the first image looks useful, please [edit]  your question to include that after you've read [mcve].